# Issue with char, varchar, decimal in Sqoop command with --map-column-hive tag

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am importing data from teradata to hive using Sqoop.

I added `--map-column-hive` in sqoop import command

`--map-column-hive col1=int,col2=float,col3=decimal,col4=timestamp,col5=varchar`

I got exception:

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:234 mismatched input ',' expecting ( near 'varchar' in primitive type specification

Then I tried:

`--map-column-hive col1=int,col2=float,col3=decimal,col4=timestamp,col5=varchar(255)`

I got:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

How to handle `char`, `varchar` and `decimal` in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking source code and tracking issue related to this. I found:

For `--map-column-hive` tag

1. **Without precision and scale**

   key=value

   e.g. `col1=int`
2. **With Precision**

   key = "value(precision)" (*can be in single quotes*)

   e.g. `col2="varchar(255)"`
3. **With Scale**

   There is a bug for this, fixed in Sqoop 1.4.7

   Fix is not straightforward. 
   For example, for a column `col3=decimal(1,1)` one need to write `col3=decimal(1%2C1)`

   Check [SQOOP-2103 issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2103) for more details